# Rotate object based on touch event

Tags: ios, swift

So as part of an idea I had for a fun little game I need an object in the middle (in portrait view) to rotate left when I touch the left side of the screen and rotate right when I touch the right side of the screen.

That's literally it.

But I want to use swift and not objective-C... all the tutorials I find are for obj-c and as a result I don't understand how to implement the coding into the GameScene.swift file.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think It would be SpriteKit. So you need:

1) add a SpriteNode in the center of your screen

2) define touch location

3) and if frame.size.width > or < that location on x axis of your touch so you need to run some animation by you created SpriteNode.

So it's pretty easy, but you need to write some code to get more detailed help.

Comment: Thanks! I think i'll just get going with this for now! cheers though

Comment: if I'm correct please mark my answer as correct one

Comment: Sorry, have done! :)

Answer (score 2):

What Wm.p1us said is correct, here is the code for what he suggested.

```
   var myImage: SKSpriteNode!

   class GameScene: SKScene {
        override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

            anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)

            myImage = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "myImage")
            addChild(myImage)

   }

   override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

            let touch = touches.first as UITouch!
            let location = touch.locationInView(self.view)

            myImage.removeAllActions()

            if location.x < frame.size.width/2 {
                // left hand side touched, rotate left

                let rotateLeft = SKAction.rotateByAngle(CGFloat(M_PI)*2, duration: 1)
                myImage.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(rotateLeft))

            } else {
               // right hand side touched, rotate right

                let rotateRight = SKAction.rotateByAngle(-CGFloat(M_PI)*2, duration: 1)
                myImage.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(rotateRight))

            }

        }
    }
```